# How To authenticate ALM from C# Windows Application Using Rest API

Tags: c#, rest, authentication, alm

I am bit stuck here, trying to Integrate ALM using Rest API from C# Window application . But failed at the first step that is authentication .

Here is my Authentication call :

```
public void auth(string url, string xml)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        byte[] requestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml.ToString());
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/xml";
        req.Accept = "application/xml";
        req.KeepAlive = true;
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        req.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;
        Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default);
        backstr = sr.ReadToEnd();
        myheader = res.Headers.Get("Set-Cookie");
        sr.Close();
        res.Close();

    }
```

which i am calling like this :

```
 try
        {
            // my creds, server details
            string server_ = @"https://MyAlmUrl";
            string  user_ = "username";
            string password_ = "password";
            string xmll = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><alm-authentication><user>" + user_ + "</user><password>" + password_ + "</password></alm-authentication>";
            rest.auth(server_ + "/authentication-point/authenticate", xmll);
        }
```

No matter what ever i do It lands into : `401 unauthorized error`.

I do have a valid credentials as i am able to login using the web with same credentials .

Some one help me out, what i am doing wrong , As This ALM and using Rest API , both are new to me .

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
  HttpWebRequest myauthrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://{qcserver}/qcbin/authentication-point/alm-authenticate");

        string AuthenticationXML = @"<alm-authentication>
                        <user>{qcserver-username}</user>                
                        <password>{qcserver-pwd}</password>       
                        </alm-authentication>";

        byte[] Requestbytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AuthenticationXML);
        myauthrequest.Method = "POST";
        myauthrequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
        myauthrequest.ContentLength = Requestbytes.Length;
        myauthrequest.Accept = "application/xml";
        Stream RequestStr = myauthrequest.GetRequestStream();
        RequestStr.Write(Requestbytes, 0, Requestbytes.Length);
        RequestStr.Close();
        HttpWebResponse myauthres = (HttpWebResponse)myauthrequest.GetResponse();
        var AuthenticationCookie = myauthres.Headers.Get("Set-Cookie");

       //request to get all domains in ALM
        HttpWebRequest domainreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://{qcserver}/qcbin/rest/domains/");
        domainreq.Method = "GET";
        domainreq.ContentType = "application/xml";
        domainreq.Accept = "application/xml";
        domainreq.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, AuthenticationCookie);
        HttpWebResponse domainres= (HttpWebResponse)domainreq.GetResponse();
        Stream RStream = domainres.GetResponseStream();
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(RStream);

       //request to dowmload a particular attachement assigned to a test case
       HttpWebRequest attachmentreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://{qcserver}/qcbin/rest/domains/{domainname}/project/{projectname}/tests/{testid}/attachments/file.xls");
        attachmentreq.Method = "GET";
        attachmentreq.ContentType = "application/xml";
        attachmentreq.Accept = "application/octet-stream";
        attachmentreq.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, AuthenticationCookie);
        HttpWebResponse attachmentres= (HttpWebResponse)attachmentreq.GetResponse();
        Stream RStream = attachmentres.GetResponseStream();
        var fileStream = File.Create("C:\\PathToFile");
        RStream.InputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        fileStream.Close();
```

Comment: Getting all domains in ALM failed: System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (401) Authentication failed. Browser based integrations - to login append '?login-form-required=y' to the url you tried to access..' 

line: HttpWebResponse domainres = (HttpWebResponse)domainreq.GetResponse();